# Enable global ESlint config

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, eslintrc

I want to make a eslint config works globally, so that I don't need to init it in each project.

then I installed eslint and some config extension globally.

```
npm install -g eslint eslint-config-airbnb eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-react-hooks
```

And this is my eslint config file **~/.eslintrc.json**

```
{
 "env": {
 "browser": true,
 "es6": true,
 "node": true
 },
 "extends": [
 "airbnb-base"
 ],
 "rules": {
 }
}
```

But I got error when I lint my js file

```
ESLint couldn't find the config "airbnb-base" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.

The config "airbnb-base" was referenced from the config file in "/home/molly/.eslintrc.json".
```

This is my global installed packages, airbnb is there.
[image]

Did I miss something ? I don't want to install eslint-plugin** in each of project

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late for you but I don't think you can install eslint plugins globally.
The way around that worked for me is to create a directory where all my projects go and inside that directory create a `package.json` (`npm init -y`) and install all the plugins in that directory `npm i -D eslint-config-airbnb eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-react-hooks`

Bring your global `.eslintrc` file in that directory which will act like a root eslint config for all your projects that's inside that directory now.

Essentially, your directory tree should like the following now:

```
projects/
  package.json
  .eslintrc
  node_modules/
    ...
  my_cool_project/
    ...
  my_cool_project2/
    ...
  ...
```